# Rails database name dynamically by user choice in Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

While installing my app , I want to ask question like
 Name of database?
and user will input name they want for database.
Database name is inside config/mongoid.yml

```
development:
       sessions:
    default:
          database: project_development
          hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
```

I want to make the database like project_development dynamically by user input while performing bundle install or before bundle install for app.Is there any steps to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If config/mongoid.yml is passed through ERB like config/database.yml is, then you can do the following trick:

```
development:
   sessions:
default:
      database: <%= ENV['MONGO_DB_NAME'] || 'default_db_name' %>
      hosts:
    - localhost:27017
  options:
```

Then start rails with `MONGO_DB_NAME=some_name rails s`. If you omit MONGO_DB_NAME from startup, it will fallback to `default_db_name`.

Comment: May be my question is silly but is it possible.  First i run rails s   Which use default database name  and in another time i use another port to run the same project in different database name like    MONGO_DB_NAME=yak_name rails s -p 3002
Here in two ports i want to run same project but with different database name.. I did like this but i get error A server is already running. Check /home/prem/Desktop/Rails cast/102-auto-complete-association-revised/token/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Isn't it possible to run same project in different ports with different database at same time?

Comment: Just check out a copy of your project into a different directory and you will be able to run rails s from both locations on different ports.